# Why declare AngularJs at the bottom if it's initialised in DomContentLoaded

Tags: angularjs, domcontentloaded

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

In this guide it says "Placing script tags at the end of the page improves app load time because the HTML loading is not blocked by loading of the angular.js"

But what exactly does it mean in the next statement "Angular initializes automatically upon DOMContentLoaded event". Can anyone explain what this initialize means and then how angular.js can block the HTML loading?

Comment: Loading a JS file blocks the browser.

Comment: Loading a js file only blocks the browser if its declared in the html HEAD element.

Comment: @DamianNikodem It does when is at the bottom, too, it just doesn't *matter* because essentially the entire page had already loaded and can render.

Comment: @DaveNewton loading .js or .css files will not block if in the body element of a HTML document. You can test this by inserting a known slow script at the top of the body element and watching the rest of the content render as the .js loads.

Comment: @DamianNikodem https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-javascript/9781449382308/ch01.html, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/, etc. They'll block images from loading, rendering since the js could modify the render, etc. I (and the Internet) could be wrong, but I'd like to see some citations to back it up.

Comment: @DaveNewton http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html , look at the force-async internal attribute in the specification, scripts which are not parser-inserted (e.g. appended as a new dom node such as a framework like requrejs ) and contain a src attribute then they will get flagged as force async, This image ( http://imgur.com/Ig7HXPD ) shows clearly 3 scripts being loaded in the head element at the same time. Whereas this image ( http://imgur.com/GF0oW2M ) is from a slightly newer version of one of the same app which loads the JS at the top of the body,  you can see the png's start time.

Comment: Loading scripts asynchronously is a different thing than rendering, though. But a good resource, thanks. Perhaps the confusion is because I used the term "block" nebulously, I don't mean nothing else can happen-the issue is rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the HTML parser comes across any script elements, It assumes that `document.write` may be present in the script and it blocks HTML loading. That's why it's recommended to load all scripts at the bottom of the page to ensure page loads fast.

By the statement, `Angular initializes automatically upon DOMContentLoaded event`, it means that angular bootstraps the app once the DOM is ready.

Comment: Excuse me but I'm new to angular and haven't delved into DOM page life cycles very much, but can bootstrapping the app with angular occur without having loaded the angular.js file, that is if the angular.js file is only loaded at the bottom when the HTML parser gets to it - it can still bootstrap the app in DOMcontentloaded?

Comment: No. only if the angular.js file is loaded it can bootstrap the app. If the angular.js file is at the bottom of the page, by default the DOM would be ready. So angular will start bootstrapping the app.

Comment: Even if you place the angular.js file at the <head> section. It will start bootstrapping the app only if the DOM is ready.

Comment: It's been a bit vague about what it means when angular is initialized in DOMcontentloaded - that it's just a call for bootstrapping to occur once the DOM is ready, not that anything is actually loaded. Thanks heaps.

Comment: @Pr0ph3t How could Angular initialize if its code hasn't been loaded?